# CSS Text Overlapping

Tags: html, css, text, overlapping

How can I achieve something like

this

[image]

[image]

I've tried margins and padding but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: Lower `z-index` on text.

Comment: `z-index` can be applied only if the text element is positioned.

Comment: Question isn't very clear. What exactly is "this" given the two samples?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UuEJ2/.

HTML:

```
<h1>Sample Text</h1>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 48px/1 Sans-Serif;
    background-color: #5e5e5e;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `height` property and use `em` value can achieve the desire effect. Now if you increase the font size the effect still will be same. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lovepide/1/)**.

**CSS**

```
h1{background:gold;  height:.9em;font-size:5em;color:white;overflow: hidden;}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Sample Text</h1>
```

Comment: Does My answer helpful for you?

Comment: can you close this answer just clicking on green check mark icon?